# URL-encoded query params are incorrectly parsed by Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm having some trouble with testing my controller sending params:
I'm sending the following map:

```
params = %{
  "filter" => %{
    "type" => "all",
    "conditions" => [
      %{"column" => "price", "comparator" => "equals", "value" => "120", "type" => "number"} 
    ]
  } 
}
```

in the call:

```
conn = get conn, property_path(conn, :index, params)
```

But in the controller, when I inspect the received params, I get:

```
%{
  "filter" => %{
    "conditions" => [
      %{"column" => "price"},
      %{"comparator" => "equals"}, 
      %{"type" => "number"}, 
      %{"value" => "120"}
    ],
    "type" => "all"
  }
}
```

The single item in the array got converted to an array that each key/value is a map itself. Is there a way to get the same map as the controller params?

Comment: This might be a bug. Here's the query generated by PHP's `http_build_query` for the same data - https://3v4l.org/Noi5v. Phoenix parses this almost correctly (it returns a map with key "0" instead of a list).

Comment: `Plug.Conn.Query.encode(%{a: [%{b: 2, c: 3}]}) == Plug.Conn.Query.encode(%{a: [%{b: 2}, %{c: 3}]}) #=> true`

Comment: There is a pull request that apparently fix this: It's not in the latest version in the current data, but should be in the next one: https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/pull/52/files

Comment: That looks like the PR that initially added the feature 2 years ago. Did you mean to link to something else?

Comment: Oh, damn, just saw the day and month and not the year. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As José Valim replied in the [issue](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug/issues/428) created in [Plug](https://github.com/elixir-lang/plug), it's not possible to encode effectively because there is some ambiguity when encoding the list.

The solution is to encode the parameters using maps instead of lists:

```
params = %{
   "filter" => %{
     "type" => "all",
     "conditions" => %{
        0 => %{"column" => "price", "comparator" => "equals", "value" => "120", "type" => "number"}
     }
   }
 }
```